# Config files for different production builds React

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, runtime, config, dev-to-production

I have a React App that will be deployed as several individual apps that differ very slightly. Some texts will be different in some places, API URL may be different, language etc.

How would i go about solving this problem? I basically want to be able to build once and the app to change its functionality from a config file that sits in the build folder... is that possible? Or is there any other way to solve this that i'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a config.json file and store all your changes there, you could probably have something like:

ENV

```
REACT_APP_ID=APP_1
```

config.json

```
APP_1: { name: 'app one', lang: '/path/to/lang', api_basepath: 'path/to/api' }
```

and then use that in your code with something like

```
import conf from './conf.json';

const useConfigData = key => conf[process.env.REACT_APP_ID][key]

const api = useConfigData('api_basepath');
const myFetch = () => {
  fetch(`${api}/some_endpoint`).then()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this still requires that i build it 4 times with different APP_ID for each though right? Since it cannot read env variables at runtime?

Comment: Yea correct, then probably instead of having the APP_ID coming from the env file you should have that coming from a config file that sits on your public folder, this way you can then change the corresponding file in the build and expect your app to read that file

Comment: Thanks! That's what i did :) I added a config file and <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/config.js"></script> in index.html. Thanks for the help, very much appreciated!